# What degree of knowledge overlap would I see between Backbone.js and WPF?

Tags: javascript, wpf, backbone.js

This may seem like a really off-the-wall question, but I've been learning how Backbone.js works and I've recently been asked about creating a WPF project at work.

For those of you who have worked with both, would knowledge of the Backbone.js framework be beneficial for starting on a WPF application?

For instance, you create Views in Backbone that manage the data and rendering of templates in the html page.

If you look at this in terms of the way WPF has a ViewModel that manages the XAML files, would you say that certain skills would be tranferable?  If so, what aspects of the way that Backbone.js works would be immediately apparent when I'm working in WPF?

I realize that WPF is a proprietary MS technology that uses MVVM and Backbone is an open-source JS framework that uses a modified MVC pattern.  I'm just trying to see if I can transfer what I already know onto WPF.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very little transfers over IMO.  Both have a declarative markup (HTML vs XAML) and both have an imperative programming language (JS/CoffeeScript vs C#/VB.Net).  Other than that, the paradigms are very different.

To get close, you might look at [RestSharp](http://restsharp.org/) to manage your models/REST services.  ViewModels in WPF and Views in Backbone.js are analogous but not very similar.  ViewModels are views of the model or models of the view, but they don't tend to contain view-specific code.  Code behind might.  Sometimes it feels like Backbone.js views are similar to WPF ViewModels AND code behind.

You might also look at [Magellen](http://www.paulstovell.com/magellan) for routing and MVC capabilities in WPF that have some similarities to the routing that happens in Backbone.js.

The markup in XAML is significantly different than in HTML.  You have a full-blown component model which is significantly more capable than Backbone.js but this is just a limitation of HTML and not so much Backbone.  Further, XAML has two-way data binding built into the markup (as opposed to doing it in the views in Backbone).  The markup also has state management and transitions available to you which is often handled in jQuery when working in Backbone.

Oh yeah, there is no jQuery in WPF, but that is probably obvious.

Your code organization skills from Backbone are likely to translate well.  Your strong understanding of separation of concerns (SOC) and single responsibility are also likely to help when developing WPF apps.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks so much for the detailed answer Brian.  I've never heard of Magellen before - I will definitely check that out.